# create bar chart from select table row(s) for select column

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

The code below creates a bar chart but does not use the included data table.  I would like to create the chart for an arbitrary year by specifying the year and using the table. Possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Year,A,B,C,D,E
2011,14.80,9.50,2.27,1.13,-0.15
2012,15.80,10.50,2.57,2.13,-0.25
2013,16.80,11.50,2.67,3.13,-0.50
}\datatable
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar,
    ylabel=2013, %wanted: take from specified Year
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.1,.5)},anchor=south}, %odd but needed
    x=1.5cm,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=16.8,  %wanted: take from column A for specified Year
    tick pos=left,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    bar width=25pt,
    symbolic x coords={B,C,D,E}, %wanted: specify subset of header row
    xtick={B,C,D,E}, %wanted: take from symbolic x coords
    nodes near coords,
    %axis lines*=left,
    ]
\addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=blue!50] coordinates {(B,11.50) (C,2.67) (D,3.13)};
\addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=red!50]  coordinates {(E,0.50)}; %note change of sign and color
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the color change for the last bar happen automatically? What's the criterium for the color change? The sign of the value doesn't change, maybe you meant that it should be red if it's smaller than unity?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.  The code includes the comment "note the change of sign and color": color changes to red for negative values, which are then plotted as if positive.  (In the specific case, this can happen only in column E.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Please have a look at the comments in the code for more details.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the advanced features for
        % axis label positioning
        compat=1.3,
    }
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        Year,A,B,C,D,E
        2011,14.80,9.50,2.27,1.13,-0.15
        2012,15.80,10.50,2.57,2.13,-0.25
        2013,16.80,11.50,2.67,3.13,-0.50
    }\datatable
    % do have a simple solution, transpose the data table
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[
        colnames from={Year},
    ]{\transposeddatatable}{\datatable}
    % =========================================================================
    % here you specify the year you want to plot
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Year}{2013}
    % =========================================================================
    % now we can extract the `ymax' value from the transposed table
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{\Year}\of{\transposeddatatable}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x=1.5cm,
        ybar,
        bar width=25pt,
        bar shift=0pt,
        % simply apply the stored value here for the chosen year
        ylabel=\Year,
        ymin=-0.1,
        % the same here. Just supply the stored value for the `ymax' value
        ymax=\ymax,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        % instead of using `symbolic x coords' we do it a bit different,
        % because then we don't get into trouble "deleting"/skipping the "A"
        % value from the table, which should not be plotted here
        %
        % just use integers to a sufficiently high number so that all bars
        % will have a tick ...
        xtick=data,
        % ... and use as labels the values from the transposed table
        xticklabels from table={\transposeddatatable}{colnames},
        % to skip the "A" value filter it away
        x filter/.expression={x==0 ? NaN : x},
        % this is used to filter the "negative" values away
        % (this also works for filtering the "positive" values away, since the
        %  filter is applied *after* `y expr' is evaluated, so the former
        %  former positive values are now negative and vice versa)
        y filter/.expression={y<0 ? NaN : y},
        nodes near coords,
        tick pos=left,
    ]
        \addplot [
            fill=blue!50,
        ] table [
            % we use `\coordindex' as x value, which now matches the `xtick's
            % and the corresponding labels
            x expr=\coordindex,
            % of course here we want to simply the values from the corresponding
            % chosen year
            y=\Year,
        ] {\transposeddatatable};

        \addplot [
            fill=red!50,
        ] table [
            x expr=\coordindex,
            % here we also want to use the values from the corresponding year,
            % but we want to plot the negative of that value why we use
            % `y expr' here and thus need `\thisrow'
            y expr=-\thisrow{\Year},
        ] {\transposeddatatable};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%    % for debugging purposes only
%    \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\transposeddatatable}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]